# How to hide Edit and Delete actions from Show view in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

just added Active Admin to my project. I want hide the Edit & Delete action form the Show page, and Edit & Delete action should present in Index page.

Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about ActiveAdmin, but on RailsAdmin I did it easily with cancan. Just setting corresponding rights.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try

```
ActiveAdmin.register FooBar do
    config.action_items.delete_if { |item|
      # item is an ActiveAdmin::ActionItem
      item.display_on?(:show)
    }

end
```

?

you can find other workarounds in this thread https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/760